# Restore and Recovery scenario

Tags: oracle-11g

I want to restore and recover my oracle database to the current state.

For example, I have a full backup on Sunday and I have all archive logs from Sunday to Wednesday.

If I restore and recover from backup to the new host, my database is in the state of Sunday only.

How can I apply all archive logs I have to recover my database to the state of Wednesday?

Do I need controlfile autobackup on Sunday or the current one on Wednesday?

Please give me steps to do this.

Regards,
Sarith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, take the latest image you have in standby mode, and start it up

```
 connect internal; 
 startup nomount; 
 alter database mount standby database;
```

Then place your archive logs (or Sunday's, if you've got them segregated by day) where they belong and do

```
 recover standby database;
```

It's going to prompt you for a filename. Since that filename should be in your Sunday logs, just type AUTO.

The way I do it on my databases is to have a large filesystem specifically for archive logs called /db_archive and each day is a directory under there. My oracle instance is under /db and it looks for my archive logs under /db/archive, so when I recover a specific day's logs, I link /db_archive/DATE -> /db/archive

It's not optimum, but I'm dealing with Oracle 8i, and many years ago the database wasn't setup ideally. Hopefully soon we'll migrate to Oracle 11 and I won't have to do all of this crap.